# Is this a valid proof of the euclidean algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, algorithms, solution-verification, euclidean-algorithm

I created a proof of the euclidean algorithm and since I'm not really familiar with the field of discrete mathematics I'm asking for a revision :

Having two natural numbers $a$ and $b$ we follow this procedure :

$1)$ If $a=b \implies GCD(a,b) = a  = b \:$   and stop.

$2)$ First of all I write :

$$a = GCD(a,b)\cdot q \\
b = GCD(a,b)\cdot r$$

so because of definition $q$ and $r$ are coprime.

Say $\max(a,b) = a$ then take :

$$a' = a - b = GCD(a,b)\cdot q - GCD(a,b)\cdot r = GCD(a,b)\cdot (q-r)$$

So it's sure that :

$$GCD(a',b) = GCD(a,b)\cdot s  $$

if $s = 1$ then the proof is complete, this is equivalent to $q-r$ and $r$ being coprime :

So suppose $q-r$ and $r$ a being not coprime then $q-r = k\cdot w\:$ and $\:r = k\cdot p \:$ (with $k>1$), but then :

$$ q = k\cdot w + r \implies \frac{q}{r} = \frac{k\cdot w + r}{k\cdot p} = \frac{w}{p} + 1 = \frac{w+p}{p} $$

This is a contradiction because $q$ and $r$ are coprime , but $p<r$   **and** $w+p<q$, so $q-r$ and $r$ are also coprime , then :

$$GCD(a',b) = GCD(a,b)  $$

$3)$ Reiterate the first two steps (with $a'$ instead of $a$ in this case ) until $1)$ is true

Besides , the procedure has a finite number of steps , because the algorithm produces always a pair $(a,b) = ( GCD(a,b)\cdot q,
GCD(a,b)\cdot r) $ and since either $q$ or $r$ is reduced at every iteration , then the pair will become $(GCD(a,b),GCD(a,b))$ at the end of the procedure  (taking for example the condition of $\max(a,b) = a $ in $2)$ we have $a' < a $ ) .

The way I'm writing it can be confusing because it's a mixture of the steps of the algorithm and the proof of it , but somehow I find it clearer .

Comment: Well, in that case, you could say that at each iteration, you will always have a pair $(GCD(a, b)m, GCD(a, b)n),$  and since these numbers are always decreasing, at some point they will be equal; just saying that the algorithm will reach that point because the numbers decrease at each step might not be that obvious I guess, but so far, the algorithm looks good to me :)

Comment: Still didn't get the proof of $q - r$ and $r$ being coprime, though

Comment: thanks , I really appreciate your help!

Comment: But, by definition, $q$ and $r$ are already coprime, so $GCD(q-r, r) = GCD(q,r) = 1$ because of the properties of $GCD$. I think this would be an easier way to show what you need to get the step right. I can't say 'wrong', I just don't see where's the contradiction exactly

Comment: I updated , now it should be better explained

Comment: @Jose Ramirez Does it sound good to you now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108687/discussion-between-jose-ramirez-and-tortar).